# Cannot remove package touchegg

Tags: touchegg

I would like to remove touchegg with

```
sudo apt-get purge touchegg
```

but the output says that nothing was uninstalled. When I check

```
dpkg -l
```

touchegg is not listed among the packages so so far so good. But strangely when I call touchegg from the terminal it still runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to reboot your computer after removal, the program could still be in memory. Then use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And

```
sudo updatedb
```

If this dont work, It could be possible that your program "touchegg" is in the `/usr/bin` , `/bin` folder or another included in the PATH. Try, after doing the above commands, to use:

```
locate touchegg
```

It will tell you where the program, or related files containing the same name are located.

Comment: You should explain that it might still run after purging because it's still in RAM. Good answer though.

Comment: Oh, thats true, thanks for the suggestion. Should I put that in the answer, or leave it in your comment? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The first steps didn't yield the desired results, so after locating it I found it in several locations on the disk `/usr/local/share` and `/home/$USER/touchegg/`. Do I remove these manually?

Comment: Well, that's very strange, try to use `sudo apt-get remove touchegg` first, then repeat the procedure above. If this don't work, try to remove the files manually as you are asking. Regards

Comment: Alright, removing the files manually did the job. Thanks!