# How to remove installed package

Tags: dpkg, uninstall, configuration

OK I have downloaded and installed Erlang Solutions with

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
```

But made a mistake when installing

```
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
```

selecting my ubuntu distribution as `yakkety yak` instead of `xenial` and I'm trying to uninstall using

```
sudo apt-get remove  --purge erlang-solutions
```

but when I reinstall the package I'm not prompted to enter the ubuntu version, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebooted your PC after removal? Some files could still be in memory, so, reboot first before reinstall. If the problem persist, it could be that, some configuration or residual files are still be present in disk. You can manually delete the related files searching for them, and deleting manually.
To do so, try with

```
sudo updatedb
locate <fileName>
```

Where *fileName* is the file you want to seach. For example:

```
locate erlang-solutions
```

This will list all the files which name contains the string erlang-solutions. Then, you can delete it with

```
sudo rm <fileName>
```

But, be careful!, look at the absolute path of the file, you don't want to delete system files or sensible data.

You can also look at this thread for more information about a related issue:

[Cannot Remove touchegg package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818312/cannot-remove-package-touchegg/818315#818315)

Comment: Did not work, but I just had to change the name in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d dir for erlang, from yakkety yak to xenial. Thanks